# iphone: scale when using glgif library

Tags: iphone, animated-gif

I am using glgif to display some gif picture on iphone, the gif is be downloaded from web. I display it on iphone successfully but the picture seems wrong scale. It happened to many pictures. Can anyone suggest me to fix this? I dig in to glgif but can not find a way to fix.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Uncomment `[self setAspectScale:YES];` inside `-(void)startAnimation:(Video*)video;`